# The existence of a decomposition of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A$ be a bounded (continuous) linear map whose spectrum is disjoint from the annulus $\{z: a\leq |z|\leq b\}$, for some $0<a\leq b$. Then, can we find $X_1$ and $X_2$, such that $X=X_1\oplus X_2$, $A_1=A|_{X_1}$ has spectrum in $\{z: |z|> b\}$ and $A_2=A|_{X_2}$ has spectrum in $\{z: |z|<a\}$?

This is a condition of Theorem 2 of a paper [D.B. Henry, some infinite-dimensinoal Morse-Smale systems defined by parabolica partial differential equations, J. Diff. Equa., 1985, 59: 165-205]. I can not understand the existence of the decomposition of $X$.

Comment: This looks like an application of continuous functional calculus. Is $A$ normal?

Comment: Oh, they are not deducing the decomposition, they are assuming it. The $A$ and $X$ are given like that in the theorem. The conclusion of the theorem are the limits of the sequences at the end. A place in which you do need to deduce the existence of the decomposition is in the Corollary that follow. But there is applied for $e^{Lt}$.

Comment: @Boxwood Yes, I think we may not deduce the decomposition. Choose $M>r(A)$ (the spectral radius of $A$). Then the annulus ${z: M\leq |z|\leq M+1}$ will be disjoint with the spectrum of $A$, but A can not be decomposed to such $A_1$ and $A_2$, because $\sigma(A)=\sigma(A_1)\cup\sigma(A_2)$.

Comment: @Boxwood This is a Banach space, not Hilbert space.